# How to apply datepicker in InnerHTML input box. Now datepicker is working fine but incremental value does not changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function addrow()
    {
        var node = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var r = 3;
        var c = 0;
    //alert(node.length);
        for(var i=0; i<node.length; i++)
        {
          //alert(node.length);
            var nod = node[i];
             if(nod.getAttribute('class') == 'newrow')
             {
                r++;
                c++;
             }
        }

         var table= document.getElementById('newtable');
           var row= table.insertRow(r);
           var cell1 =row.insertCell(0);
           var cell2 =row.insertCell(1);
           var cell3 =row.insertCell(2);
           var cell4 =row.insertCell(3);
           var cell5 =row.insertCell(4);
           var cell6 =row.insertCell(5);
           
           cell1.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' class='newrow' placeholder='date' id='date"+c+"' name='date["+c+"]' autocomplete='OFF'/>";
        
           cell2.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='time"+c+"' name='time["+c+"]'  class='input-block-level time' placeholder='time' autocomplete='OFF'/>";
        
           cell3.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='temerature"+c+"' name='temerature["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder=' temperature'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
        
           cell4.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='rlt_humidity"+c+"' name='rlt_humidity["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder='relative humidity'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
        
           cell5.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='diff_pressure"+c+"' name='diff_pressure["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder='diff pressure'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
       
           cell6.innerHTML ="<li onclick='addrow()' class='icon-plus-sign' ></li><li onclick='DeleteRow()' class='icon-remove-sign' ></li> ";
    }

        
     function DeleteRow(){

    var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     var r=2;
     
     for (var i=0; i<node_list.length; i++) {
         var node = node_list[i];
          if (node.getAttribute('class') == 'newrow') {
               r++;
          }
      }
     document.getElementById("newtable").deleteRow(r);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body  onload="addrow()">
    <div style="border:1px solid black; width:80%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" class="col-md-12">
    <form method="post" action="#">

     <div class="col-md-12">

                                <div style="font-weight: bolder;margin-bottom: 10px;font-size: 18px;"><center>ENVIRONMENT CONTROL OF PACKING AREA</center> </div>
                                <!--<div style="font-weight: bolder;font-size:15px;margin-left: 30px;" >Date:</div>-->
                               <div style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 80px;">
                                        <table id="newtable" class="table table-bordered">
                                          <thead >
                                            <tr>
                                                <th rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:top"><center>Date</center></th>
                                                <th rowspan="3"  style="vertical-align:top"><center>Time</center></th>
                                                <th colspan="3"><center>Parameter</center></th>
                                                <th rowspan="3"></th>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <th>Temperature</th>
                                                <th>Relative Humidity</th>
                                                <th>Differential  pressure</th>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <th style="width:149px;">≤ 30 ºc</th>
                                                <th style="width:158px;" >≤ 50 %</th>
                                                <th style="width:150px;">0.2 to 0.8 mm</th>
                                              </tr>

                                          </thead>

                                      </table>
                                 </div>
                                  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left:520px;">Submit</button>

                 <div style="margin-top: 80px;margin-bottom: 100px;">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Production Chemist  Sign &date</th>
                          <th>QA Chemist&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          Sign &date</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="height: 100px;"></td>
                          <td style="height: 100px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                </table>
             </div>



     </div>


      </div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     
      </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 function datepick(c) {
  alert(c);
    $("#date"+c).datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'});  
  }

function addrow()
{
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var r = 3;
    var c = 0;
//alert(node.length);
    for(var i=0; i<node.length; i++)
    {
      //alert(node.length);
        var nod = node[i];
         if(nod.getAttribute('class') == 'newrow')
         {
            r++;
            c++;
         }
    }

     var table= document.getElementById('newtable');
       var row= table.insertRow(r);
       var cell1 =row.insertCell(0);
       var cell2 =row.insertCell(1);
       var cell3 =row.insertCell(2);
       var cell4 =row.insertCell(3);
       var cell5 =row.insertCell(4);
       var cell6 =row.insertCell(5);
       
       cell1.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' class='newrow' placeholder='date' id='date"+c+"' name='date["+c+"]' autocomplete='OFF' onClick='datepick("+c+")'/>";
    
       cell2.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='time"+c+"' name='time["+c+"]'  class='input-block-level time' placeholder='time' autocomplete='OFF'/>";
    
       cell3.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='temerature"+c+"' name='temerature["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder=' temperature'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
    
       cell4.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='rlt_humidity"+c+"' name='rlt_humidity["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder='relative humidity'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
    
       cell5.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='diff_pressure"+c+"' name='diff_pressure["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder='diff pressure'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
   
       cell6.innerHTML ="<li onclick='addrow()' class='icon-plus-sign' ></li><li onclick='DeleteRow()' class='icon-remove-sign' ></li> ";
}

    
 function DeleteRow(){

var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 var r=2;
 
 for (var i=0; i<node_list.length; i++) {
     var node = node_list[i];
      if (node.getAttribute('class') == 'newrow') {
           r++;
      }
  }
 document.getElementById("newtable").deleteRow(r);
}
</script>
</head>
<body  onload="addrow()">
<div style="border:1px solid black; width:80%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" class="col-md-12">
<form method="post" action="#">

 <div class="col-md-12">

                            <div style="font-weight: bolder;margin-bottom: 10px;font-size: 18px;"><center>ENVIRONMENT CONTROL OF PACKING AREA</center> </div>
                            <!--<div style="font-weight: bolder;font-size:15px;margin-left: 30px;" >Date:</div>-->
                           <div style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 80px;">
                                    <table id="newtable" class="table table-bordered">
                                      <thead >
                                        <tr>
                                            <th rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:top"><center>Date</center></th>
                                            <th rowspan="3"  style="vertical-align:top"><center>Time</center></th>
                                            <th colspan="3"><center>Parameter</center></th>
                                            <th rowspan="3"></th>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <th>Temperature</th>
                                            <th>Relative Humidity</th>
                                            <th>Differential  pressure</th>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <th style="width:149px;">≤ 30 ºc</th>
                                            <th style="width:158px;" >≤ 50 %</th>
                                            <th style="width:150px;">0.2 to 0.8 mm</th>
                                          </tr>

                                      </thead>

                                  </table>
                             </div>
                              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left:520px;">Submit</button>

             <div style="margin-top: 80px;margin-bottom: 100px;">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Production Chemist  Sign &date</th>
                      <th>QA Chemist&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          Sign &date</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="height: 100px;"></td>
                      <td style="height: 100px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>



 </div>


  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the snippet there is a dynamic row add and delete function in it but when i will add datepick function. datepicker is work fine but the value of c and r variable are not increment. if i remove the datepicker function which name has datepick the loop will be work fine and the values of c and r variable also be change. so please anyone help me for work these properly.
I want datepicker in date column and also change the id and name of each rows input box will be incremented by 1, such as first rows input box have a **name** is **date[0]** and **id** is **date0** after click on plus sign second row will be added and the **name** of input box is **date[1]** and **id** is **date1**.

**Please check both snippet.**

**Wanted Output is new row added at last position and in every input box of date field should be datepicker.**

Comment: C and r does get changed. The variable names will not be date[0] but it will be date["0"]. Remove double quotes and it will be as expected.

Comment: please check carefully with inspect

Comment: Sorry... It is correct. date[0] etc...

Comment: no problem sir.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes I do it.
I used span tag in first td with "newrow" class and now it works fine.**

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function addrow()
{
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var r = 3;
    var c = 0;
//alert(node.length);
    for(var i=0; i<node.length; i++)
    {
      //alert(node.length);
        var nod = node[i];
         if(nod.getAttribute('class') == 'newrow')
         {
            r++;
            c++;
         }
    }

     var table= document.getElementById('newtable');
       var row= table.insertRow(r);
       var cell1 =row.insertCell(0);
       var cell2 =row.insertCell(1);
       var cell3 =row.insertCell(2);
       var cell4 =row.insertCell(3);
       var cell5 =row.insertCell(4);
       var cell6 =row.insertCell(5);
       
        cell1.innerHTML ="<span class='newrow'></span><input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' class='datepicker' placeholder='date' id='date"+c+"' name='date["+c+"]' autocomplete='OFF' />";
    
       cell2.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='time"+c+"' name='time["+c+"]'  class='input-block-level time' placeholder='time' autocomplete='OFF'/>";
    
       cell3.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='temerature"+c+"' name='temerature["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder=' temperature'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
    
       cell4.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='rlt_humidity"+c+"' name='rlt_humidity["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder='relative humidity'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
    
       cell5.innerHTML ="<input type='text' style='width:98%;height:30px;' id='diff_pressure"+c+"' name='diff_pressure["+c+"]' class='input-block-level' placeholder='diff pressure'  autocomplete='OFF'/>";
   
       cell6.innerHTML ="<li onclick='addrow()' class='icon-plus-sign' ></li><li onclick='DeleteRow()' class='icon-remove-sign' ></li> ";
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          maxDate: '0',
          onClose: function () {
            $(this).focus();  
          }
        });
    });
  }

    
 function DeleteRow(){

var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
 var r=2;
 
 for (var i=0; i<node_list.length; i++) {
     var node = node_list[i];
      if (node.getAttribute('class') == 'newrow') {
           r++;
      }
  }
 document.getElementById("newtable").deleteRow(r);
}
</script>
</head>
<body  onload="addrow()">
<div style="border:1px solid black; width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" class="col-md-12">
<form method="post" action="#">

 <div class="col-md-12">

                            <div style="font-weight: bolder;margin-bottom: 10px;font-size: 18px;"><center>ENVIRONMENT CONTROL OF PACKING AREA</center> </div>
                            <!--<div style="font-weight: bolder;font-size:15px;margin-left: 30px;" >Date:</div>-->
                           <div style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 80px;">
                                    <table id="newtable" class="table table-bordered">
                                      <thead >
                                        <tr>
                                            <th rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:top"><center>Date</center></th>
                                            <th rowspan="3"  style="vertical-align:top"><center>Time</center></th>
                                            <th colspan="3"><center>Parameter</center></th>
                                            <th rowspan="3"></th>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <th>Temperature</th>
                                            <th>Relative Humidity</th>
                                            <th>Differential  pressure</th>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <th style="width:149px;">≤ 30 ºc</th>
                                            <th style="width:158px;" >≤ 50 %</th>
                                            <th style="width:150px;">0.2 to 0.8 mm</th>
                                          </tr>

                                      </thead>

                                  </table>
                             </div>
                              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left:520px;">Submit</button>

             <div style="margin-top: 80px;margin-bottom: 100px;">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Production Chemist  Sign &date</th>
                      <th>QA Chemist&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          Sign &date</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="height: 100px;"></td>
                      <td style="height: 100px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>



 </div>


  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**change document.getElementsByTagName('input'); to document.getElementsByTagName('span');**